# How to check if all the members of list lies in specific range

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list the form:

```
myList = {{0.12}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.14}, {0.12}, {0.14}, {0.12}, \
          {0.14}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.14}, {0.12}, \
          {0.14}, {0.12}, {0.14}, {0.12}, {0.12}, {0.14}, {0.12}}
```

How can I check if all its elements are in range `.10<x<.15`. It would be nice to have true or false as the answer.

With my limited knowledge,I have tried

```
AllTrue[myList,x_ /; `.10<x<.15`,3]
```

but I am not quite optimistic about it!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AllTrue[Flatten@myList, .1 < # < .15 &]
```

(* True *)

which @kglr finds is the fastest.

Comment: Thanks David and Picket for the quick reply...

Answer (score 4):

```
f = Through@{Min, Max}@## == {##2} &;

f[myList, .1, .15]
(* True *)
```

**Update:** Operator form of `AllTrue`:

```
AllTrue[.1 <= #[[1]] <= .15&]@myList
(* True *)
```

**Update 2:** some timings of the methods proposed so far:

```
functions = {"Through@{Min, Max}@## == {##2} &[list, min,max]",
"AllTrue[min<=#[[1]]<=max&]@list",
"AllTrue[min<=#<=max&]@Flatten[list]",
"AllTrue[Flatten@list, min<= # <=max &]",
"VectorQ[list, min <= First@# <= max &]",
"And @@ Flatten@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{min, max}], list]",
"And @@ Flatten@Function[x, min <= x <=max, Listable]@list",
"And @@ MatchQ[x_ /; min <= x <=max] @@@list",
"And @@ Thread[min <= Flatten@list <=max]",
"(#[[1]] >= min && #[[-1]] <= max ) &@Sort[Flatten@list]",
"(Min[Flatten@rlst] >= min && Max[Flatten@list] <= max )"};

rlst = List /@ RandomInteger[100, 1000000];

{min,max}={0,100};
Grid[Transpose[{functions,{f[rlst, min, max] // AbsoluteTiming ,
AllTrue[min<=#[[1]]<=max&]@rlst// AbsoluteTiming,
AllTrue[min<=#<=max&]@Flatten[rlst]// AbsoluteTiming,
AllTrue[Flatten@rlst, min<= # <=max &]// AbsoluteTiming,
VectorQ[rlst, min <= First@# <= max &] // AbsoluteTiming,
And @@ Flatten@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{min,max}], rlst]// AbsoluteTiming,
And @@ Flatten@Function[x, min <= x <=max, Listable]@rlst// AbsoluteTiming,
And @@ MatchQ[x_ /;  min <= x <=max] @@@rlst // AbsoluteTiming,
And @@ Thread[min<= Flatten@rlst <=max]// AbsoluteTiming,
(#[[1]] >= min && #[[-1]] <= max ) &@Sort[Flatten@rlst]//AbsoluteTiming,
(Min[Flatten@rlst] >= min && Max[Flatten@rlst] <= max )//AbsoluteTiming}}],
Dividers->All]
```

**{min,max}={0,100}**
[image]
**{min, max} = {0, 99}**
[image]
**{min, max} = {20, 70}**
[image]

Comment: one more: `(#[[1]] >= min  && #[[-1]] <= max ) &@Sort[Flatten@rlst]` or even `(Min[Flatten@rlst] >= min  && Max[Flatten@rlst] <= max )` ..

Comment: @george2079, I will add the two functions you suggest to the timing experiment -- it may take a day or so (i am using the free programming cloud version and i might have exceeded my daily quota today). Re `Through` , it is checking the `{Min,Max}`  of `Sequence[list, min, max]` (_not_ that of `list`; note the `##`) against `{min,max}`.

Comment: yea, I just figured that out, slick.

Answer (score 2):

A few alternatives

```
VectorQ[myList, 0.1 < First@# < 0.15 &]
(* True *)

And @@ Flatten@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0.1, 0.15}], myList]
(* True *)

And @@ Flatten@Function[x, 0.10 < x < 0.15, Listable]@myList
(* True *)

And @@ MatchQ[x_ /; 0.1 < x < 0.15] @@@ myList
(* True *)
```

Comment: Personally I like `And @@ Thread[10 < myList < 15]`

Comment: @2012rcampion Nice, for the OP's data you need `Flatten` as well `And @@ Thread[0.1 < Flatten@myList < 0.15]` but it's still short and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety:

```
in[lst_, a_, b_] := 
 Min[Sign[(# - a) (b - #)] & /@lst] /. {1 -> True, _ -> 
    False}
```

so,

```
in[Flatten@myList, 0.1, 0.15]
```

yields `True`

and `in[Flatten@myList, 0.02, 0.1]` yields `False`.

Small modification for closed or half open/closed...

Answer (score 1):

`MinMax` came with V 10.1 and `Between` with 10.3

```
And @@ Map[Between[{.12, .15}]] @ MinMax[myList]
```

True